# How to use for loop with boolean expression?

Tags: python, loops, boolean

I need to loop over nested lists and check the position of # in the list. I am using NWES(north, west, east, south) coordinates. So W should return False (because # is in that certain position), E should be True and S should also be True. I want to loop over every letter and get boolean expression for each of them. Problem is that I get False for W and it ignores E and S.
Dont know if there is indentation problem or something else.

```
def something(can_mine, moves) -> bool:
    """"""
    for i in range(len(can_mine)):
        for j in range(len(can_mine[0])):
            for k in moves:

                if can_mine[j][-1] == '#' and k == 'E':
                    return False
                    #
                elif can_mine[j][0] == '#' and k == 'W':
                    return False
                    # N works
                elif can_mine[0][j] == '#' and k == 'N':
                    return False
                    # S works
                elif can_mine[-1][j] == '#' and k == 'S':
                    return False
                else:

                    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(something([['#', '.', '.', 'x'], ['.', '.', 'x', '.'], ['.', '.', 'X', 's'], ['.', '.', 'x', 'x']], 'WES' ))

What i need is something like that:
False
True
True
What I get is:
False (which is ok)
False (should be True)
False ( should be True)
```

Comment: Can you share me the link of that problem question cos your question is not understandable with the code I can see. Please share the link of the question from where you've got this thing.

Comment: This code is a part of a bigger code for a school task I'm working on now. Basically I cant understand why after iteration it remembers False and ignores if its True.

Comment: So you want to go through each nested array and check for the condition as per the `moves`, right?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not so clear but as I was able to understand it and reading your code I have few remarks:

1. you do not need 3 nested `for` loops but `2`, one for the `moves` and one on the size of `can_mine`
2. you cannot return from a function with 1 boolean value and expect it to return 3 if you don't saves them anywhere and returning them rather then 1 boolean value
3. your `moves` loop should be the first one cause it will match your output -> if you'll have `m` moves then your output will have `m` boolean values
4. notice I initialized the output vector to `True` vector of size `m`, this is with direct contact to the fact that by default unless you entered to one of the condition you return `True`

I edited the code to match the output you specified, please see read it and explain to yourself why your code didn't work as you wished.

The code:

```
def something(can_mine, moves):
    """"""
    m = len(can_mine[0])
    res = [True for i in range(len(moves))]
    for idx, k in enumerate(moves):
        for j in range(m):
            if can_mine[j][-1] == '#' and k == 'E':
                res[idx] = False
                #
            elif can_mine[j][0] == '#' and k == 'W':
                res[idx] = False
                # N works
            elif can_mine[0][j] == '#' and k == 'N':
                res[idx] = False
                # S works
            elif can_mine[-1][j] == '#' and k == 'S':
                res[idx] = False
    return res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mine = [['#', '.', '.', 'f'], ['.', '.', 'N', '.'], ['.', '.', 'X', 's'], ['.', '.', 'j', 'X']]
    moves = 'WES'
    print(something(mine, 'WES'))
```

Output:

> [False, True, True]